# Vertical UITableView within Horizontal UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I have a horizontal `UITableView` with pagination enabled, and vertical `UITableView` within horizontal tableView. Its working fine in less than iOS 7 and not properly working in iOS 7.x.

The problem is, user can not scroll vertically, because somehow horizontal (Outer `UITableView`) scrolling has higher priority than vertical (inner `UITableView`) scrolling. How I can disable Outer `UTableView` scrolling when user scrolls vertical and vice versa

I set the **directionalLockEnabled** property as **YES**, **but not resolved**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same functionality in an app, but instead of a horizontal `UITableView` i had a `UICollectionView` the tableview was vertical and the collection view was horizontal. The functionality is nearly the same. You just have to set the property of the `UICollectionView`'s layout object to be horizontal. In the storyboard, in the sub options of a `UICollectionView` is a golden cube which is the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` object. You can select that and it contains a `scrollDirection` property to which you can set to either horizontal or vertical.

At any time i was able to pan-gesture vertically or horizontally and there was no problem, i was able to scroll what i wanted to scroll.

[UICollectionView Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it gives a solution that may be applicable.

Comment: Yes, UICollectionView is a solution, but UICollectionView is available in iOS 6.0 and later. My application supports minimum 5.0 iOS version. So can't use this solution. But It may fix, if I do this with condition as upto 6.x its working fine and in 7.x is creating issue.

Comment: oh, then you might have to create your own uicollectionview via UIScrollView.... subclass the scroll view and make a [scrollView configureWithObject:object];

Comment: sweet glad i could help

Comment: "You just have to set the property of the UICollectionView layout object to be horizontal"... which one property? @A'saDickens

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not the UICollectionView it's the Layout object associated with a UICollectionView ....